# How does WhatsApp, send messages, so that i get messages instantly, when I am online?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I know how to send data to server, how to get data from server, but I don't understand how client gets messages when both of clients are online.

I want that the client doesn't ping the server every second, but clients to get messages instantly.

I will use React JS for the UI with node JS for the server part.

Comment: Please refer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How much have you already built in react.js? Have you tead this? https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/07/14/socket-io-react-tutorial

Comment: Websockets or what you said, pings

Comment: I think you should check the websocket protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have:

- A central `server`
- `client1` (clt1) that sends the message
- `client2` (clt2) that receives the message

**When only `clt1` is online and it sends a message**:

- 1. Store the message of `clt1` in the `server`.
- 2. When `clt2` reconnects, it sends a request to the `server` to get the messages.

**When both are online**:

- 1. `clt1` sends a message to the `server`.
- 2. As the `server` knows that `clt2` is online, it **immediatly** sends the message to `clt2`.

**When only only `clt2` is online**:

- 1. `clt2` sends a request to the `server` to know if messages have been send for him/her.
- 2. If yes, get those.

It works only if the `server` knows at any moment if the clients are online or not.

Hope it helps

**EDIT:** it can also work vice versa.